# How can I annotate a calculated field into a Django queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset, inertiajs, calculated-field

How can I get a calculated field into a queryset?

Here is a code snipped:

models.py:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField()

    @property
    def calc_field(self):
        return "hi"
```

views.py:

```
test1 = Test.objects.all()
print(test[0].calc_field)  # this works, but only in the backend

test2 = Test.objects.all().values_list()
print(test[0].calc_field)  # this doesn't work
# the second one is only for demonstration purpose for what I get in the frontend
```

If I pass this data to the frontend (Vue via Inertia) I can't access the calc_field anymore. Does anyone know how I can annotate the calc_field to the queryset?

Comment: You don't. This is also one of the (very many) reaosns not to use `.values()` and `.values_list()`.